# Validation causing ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I have the following validator method:

```
static emptyControl(control: FormControl): any {

    if (!control.value || control.value=="") {
      return {
        message: "must not be empty"
      };
    }

    return null;

  }
```

If I use this on a form control then I get the error: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'null'.` If I return error instead of null, the error goes away.

First I bind the input to an uninitialized variable and then I make an async call in the ngOnInit and assign the returned value to this variable within subscribe.

What is the correct way of validating for empty/unset field?

Comment: i guess the component when intalized is empty and then value is added and you check for empty , so the values changes even before angular change detection has  been applied to it,`you can make use of required to do this i guess to check empty fields`

Comment: Angular has built in form validators for Required is basically the same as not empty. https://angular.io/api/forms/RequiredValidator

Comment: tried the built in validator. causes the same error, twice.

Comment: this article will help you https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: it didn't really help as this is to do with the validator somehow. If I don't validate same code runs without problems. I am not setting anything on the component or viewmodel from the validator as you see. So this is more like a validator issue. I suspect the value in `Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'null'` is a framework variable not one that I have defined.

Comment: @aycanadal, can you create a basic demo on stackblitz?

Comment: i was working on it will post tomorrow

Comment: Here it is, the html is a little dirty but should be ok: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evefeh?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: The problem is caused by the div that prints the errors by the way and a detect changes in ngAfterViewChecked works around the problem.

Comment: Also notice I am using form group and ngModel bindings together which is not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing template driven form and reactive form. Please choose either. Having two bindings `ngModel` and `formControl` will have such unwanted behavior some times.

Instead, set the value to the **form control** instead of your `ngModel`, i.e, remove `ngModel` completely. If you want to set a value at a later point, use `setValue`:

```
 this.someFormGroup.get('text').setValue('foo')
```

Also remove any validation from the template, so remove `required` from template and instead use `Validators.required` since you are using reactive form. Also as mentioned in comments, you do not need a custom validator here, as `Validators.required` is what you want.

Modify your template to:

```html
<div *ngIf="someFormGroup.hasError('required', 'text') && someFormGroup.controls.text.dirty">
  <label class="errorMessage"> Field is required! </label>
</div>
<form [formGroup]="someFormGroup">
  <input name="text" formControlName="text" />
</form>
```

TS:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.someFormGroup = new FormGroup({
    text: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  })
}
```

Your **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjnawp?file=app/hello.component.ts)**